# How can I fill the action parameter of a form with values from the form's input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-parameters

I know I can pass query parameters from a form and expect them in the query string:

```
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="param" value="value" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

This results in

```
http://blah-blah-blah/blah?param=value
```

However, in my webapp, I'm using path parameters. To access a single book, #459, in the library, you'd visit

```
/books/459
```

and to check one out, POST to

```
/books/459/checkout
```

where 459 is a path parameter. When I try

```
<form action="/books/{book_id}">...</form>
```

it takes me to

```
/books/%7Bbook_id%7D
```

rather than

```
/books/459
```

Do I need javascript or something to build the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Thanks to RobG
- I have used the same thing in calling WhatsApp from mobile application
- It works beautifully

  ```
  <form action="https://wa.me/" 
  onsubmit="this.action = this.action + this.mobile.value; this.submit();">
    <input type="tel" name="mobile" size="10" value="91xxxxxxxxxx"/>
    <input type="text" name="text" value="Thanks Vijayan!" />
    <input type="submit" value="WhatsApp" />
  </form>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like:

```
<form onsubmit="this.action = this.action + this.book_id.value;" ...>
```

However, making the action dependent on scripting is poor design. It is much more robust for your server to deal with the URI `...?book_id=value`, which does not require any client script at all.

Comment: I agree that using scripting to control the action is a bad idea, but I disagree with moving everything to query params, especially if the method is POST.

Comment: I don't really have the option of changing the API I'm writing -- specs and all.

Comment: +1 but I don't actually see why changing the action is bad design. Unless there is some specific objection / drawback then there is nothing wrong with the design. Please consider justifying why you believe it's bad design, or removing the assertion from the answer :)

Comment: @RudiKershaw—the reason is in the answer: "*It is much more robust for your server to deal with the URI*". Putting the logic on the server means greater confidence that it will run correctly as it removes reliance on client scripting. The value from the input is sent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating your HTML with PHP, the code below should work (untested).

```
$book_id = 459;
<form action="/books/{$book_id}">...</form>
```

Alternatively, you could dynamically modify the html using JavaScript.  It is better not to do it this way because some users may disable JavaScript. (untested)

```
$('form').attr('action','/books/' + book_id);
```